# Changing font from data-content

Tags: css

I used the code:

```
<div data-content="Reach" class="image">
```

and css:

```
.image:before {
        content: attr(data-content);
```

So is there a way to change the font-size and font family from data content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add css after content:

```
.image:before {
   content: attr(data-content);
   font-size: 42px;
}
```

Check this **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/JhQt5/)**

Comment: Don't, this is why this site exists :)